# d3.layout.stack() in d3 v5

Tags: angular, d3.js

In v3

```
const datastack = d3.layout.stack()(data);
```

In v5 I modified it to

```
const datastack = d3.stack().keys([1,2,3,4])(data);
```

But the response I got is Nan

Comment: Maybe this answers your question: [*"{d3.js} migration v3 to v4: code work on v3 (d3.layout.stack()) error v4 (d3.stack())"*](/q/38120615)

Comment: What is the data you pass to `d3.layout.stack` (in V3)?  A two-dimentional array of numbers? Can you post your data here?